# Bootstrap hide/show & slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap, and I am stuck at creating a sidebar panel just like the following:

[image: section]

[image: "+" icon]

There are two things I have not figured out how to do.

1. In the above image, when you click on the "+" icon, this section slides down. Should I specify some properties in CSS as to when it is clicked or in javascript/jquery?
2. I want to have exactly 5 checkboxes and the rest should be seen through a slider, like sliding down. I tried to do it but the section just keeps getting longer:

[image]

This is what I have done so far. I just wanted to test if it will work.

I am new to this and I do not know JavaScript or jQuery. I want to strengthen Bootstrap first and then will go for Javascript.

Comment: For the getting longer problem, look at the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) css properties

Comment: You really need to post all of your current `CODE` because posting images alone is not gonna get you any helpful answers. (you don't wanna answers to be based on guesswork)

Comment: its getting longer ??? when ??? do u want that 5 checkbox in dropdown and stylo checkbox to appear always and top4 to appear only on dropdown ???